# Using Webrat is not for Testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, webrat

Can I use Webrat in controllers? I need to make some-actions-like-user-can (facebook connect).
I just need to run webrat logic in controller - not in tests!
I need something like:

```
class PagesController  < ApplicationController
  require "webrat"
  def fb_login
    visit "http://facebook.com"
    response.should contain "It's free and always will be"
```

this is NOT working